# throwing FailMessageExchangeException a in NoOpInterceptor

Tags: java, wso2, apache-ode

I'm trying to extends NoOpInterceptor  and throw a FailMessageExchangeException, but I can't do it outside the org.apache.ode.bpel.intercept package (because has a protected constructor).. How can I trick this problem?

here's my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.esempio</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.esempio</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Esempione</name>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>wso2-maven2-repository</id>
            <url>http://dist.wso2.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>apache-Incubating-repo</id>
            <name>Maven Incubating Repository</name>
            <url>http://people.apache.org/repo/m2-incubating-repository</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>apache-maven2-repo</id>
            <name>Apache Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
         <repository>
            <id>wso2-maven2-snapshot-repository</id>
            <name>WSO2 Maven2 Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>scp://dist.wso2.org/home/httpd/dist.wso2.org/snapshots/maven2/</url>
        </repository>  


    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>org.test</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>org.test</Bundle-Name>
                        <Export-Package>
                            org.test.mediator.*,
                        </Export-Package>
                        <Import-Package>
                            *; resolution:=optional
                        </Import-Package>
                        <Fragment-Host>synapse-core</Fragment-Host>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
            </manifest>
    </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.apache.ode.wso2</groupId>
            <artifactId>ode</artifactId> 
            <version>1.3.5.wso2v8</version>     
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!--        <groupId>org.apache.ode</groupId>
            <artifactId>ode-bpel-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.6</version> -->
</project>
```

Comment: This indeed does not make sense. Please file a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ODE). Thanks.